# QT Creator configuration change to solve linking error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, linker, qt-creator

Building a QT application, I have a linking error of the following form

```
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl GLWidget::GLWidget(class QWidget *)" (??0GLWidget@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

Where `GLWidget` is a custom class derived from `QGLWidget`

My theory is that the problem is caused by a an old version of the class and that cleaning the code would solve the problem.

```
15:50:59: Running steps for project qtTest1...
15:50:59: Starting: "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.2\bin\jom.exe" clean
--- lots of lines
15:50:59: The process "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.2\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
15:50:59: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:50:59: Starting: "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.2\bin\jom.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qtbuild\qtbase\bin\uic.exe ..\qtTest1\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to clean the code doesn't seem to work and I wondering if my error would be solved if I forced QT to reconfigure itself so that the following line would not occur

> Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

Comment: Are you sure that you have `GLWidget(QWidget)` constructor defined (you have it declared, since this is compiling)?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric, I am quite confident I do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to `run qmake` command from the Qt Creator menu.